# How do I run my loop for each simulation and create a new vector with these values?

Tags: r, loops

This is my data frame:

```
time<-rep(c(1:5),4)
sim1<-rep(c(paste("sim",1)),5)
sim2<-rep(c(paste("sim",2)),5)
sim3<-rep(c(paste("sim",3)),5)
sim4<-rep(c(paste("sim",4)),5)
sim<-c(sim1,sim2,sim3,sim4)
id<-as.vector(replicate(4,sample(1:5)))

df<-data.frame(time,sim,id)

df$simnu<-as.numeric(df$sim)
```

Which should look something like this:

```
   time  sim  id simnu
1     1 sim 1  1     1
2     2 sim 1  3     1
3     3 sim 1  2     1
4     4 sim 1  4     1
5     5 sim 1  5     1
6     1 sim 2  1     2
7     2 sim 2  5     2
8     3 sim 2  4     2
9     4 sim 2  2     2
10    5 sim 2  3     2
11    1 sim 3  2     3
12    2 sim 3  3     3
13    3 sim 3  4     3
14    4 sim 3  1     3
15    5 sim 3  5     3
16    1 sim 4  3     4
17    2 sim 4  5     4
18    3 sim 4  2     4
19    4 sim 4  1     4
20    5 sim 4  4     4
```

I have created this loop that subsets the data by simulation and then calculates the output I want:

```
surveillance<-5
n<-1
simsub<-df[which(df$simnu==1),names(df)%in%c("time","sim","id")]
while (n<=surveillance){
print (n)
rndid<-df[sample(nrow(simsub),1),]
print(rndid)
if(n<rndid$time){
n<-n+1
} else {
tinf<-sum(length(df[which(simsub$time<=n),1]))
prev<-tinf/length(simsub[,1])
print(paste(prev,"prevalence"))
break
}
}
```

My question is how do I run this loop for each simulation and return the values of this as a vector?

Comment: you have a lot of things going on there, which values do you want to return as a vector exactly? can you provide an expected output?

Comment: Do you see `simsub<-df[which(df$simnu==1),names(df)%in%c("time","sim","id")]`? That command returns only the rows for simulation 1. Then I use `simsub` to run my loop on only the rows in simulation 1. What I want is for some way of repeating this command for all simulations.

Comment: `simres<-list()
n<-1
for(i in 1:length(unique(df$simnu))){
  simres[[i]]<-df[which(df$simnu==i),names(df)%in%c("time","sim","id")]
  while (n<=surveillance){
    print (n)
    rndid<-df[sample(nrow(simres[[i]]),1),]
    print(rndid)
    if(n<rndid$time){
      n<-n+1
    } else {
      tinf<-sum(length(df[which(simres[[i]]$time<=n),1]))
      prev<-tinf/length(simres[[i]][,1])
      print(paste(prev,"prevalence"))
      n<-1
      break
    }
  }
}` Is kind of what I am looking for, but this returns only the output for simulation 1. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you is to take a look at the lapply function (resp. sapply and vapply), and avoid using while, to be honest it's a bit tricky to help without really knowing what is happening in your code, but in any case here's an example how you can use lapply, however since I don't know what your code should return I can't be sure that the output is correct

I added comments and questions with your original lines, hope this helps

```
# first define a function that takes one simnu and returns whatever you want it to return
my_calc_fun <- function(sim_nr){
  ## you can subset the DF without which, names, or %in% 
  # simres[[i]] <- my_df[which(my_df$simnu==i),names(my_df)%in%c("time","sim","id")] 
  sim_df <- my_df[my_df$simnu == sim_nr, c("time","sim","id")]
  for(n in 1:surveillance){
    ## I'm not sure that is what you meant to do, 
    ## you are sampling the full DF, but you want a sample 
    ## from the subset i.e., simres[[i]]
    # rndid<-my_df[sample(nrow(simres[[i]]),1),] 
    row_id <- sample(nrow(sim_df), 1)
    rndid <- sim_df[row_id, ] 
    if(n >= rndid$time){
      ## what are you trying to sum here?
      ## because you are giving the function one number length(....)
      ## and just like above you are subsetting the full DF here
      # tinf<-sum(length(my_df[which(simres[[i]]$time<=n),1]))
      tinf <- length(sim_df[sim_df$time<=n, 1])
      # is this the value you want to return for each simnu?
      prev <- tinf/length(sim_df["time"]) 
      break
    }
  }
  return(c('simnu'=sim_nr, 'prev' = prev))
}

# apply this function on all values of simnu and save to list
result_all <- lapply(unique(my_df$simnu), my_calc_fun)
result_all
```